# One VirtualHost, multiple aliases and store access issues

Tags: multistore, redirect, apache

I'm getting 404 / apache error issues while trying to configure multiple stores having the same domain name and specific URI "directory"

## What I have done

### vhost config

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/dev-site/code"
    ServerName my.domain.local

    Alias /alias1 /var/www/html/dev-site/code
    Alias /alias2 /var/www/html/dev-site/code
    Alias /alias3 /var/www/html/dev-site/code

   <Directory /var/www/html/dev-site/code>
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride All
            RewriteEngine On
            Options +FollowSymlinks
    </Directory>

    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias1(.*) MAGE_RUN_CODE=pf_view
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias1(.*) MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias2(.*) MAGE_RUN_CODE=es_view
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias2(.*) MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store

    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias3(.*) MAGE_RUN_CODE=ta_view
    SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias3(.*) MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
</VirtualHost>
```

### Magento config

- In core_config_data, default base_url is set to "http://domain.local/" (so we can access admin at http://domain.local/admin)
- Each store base_url is set as "http://my.domain.local/aliasX/" (replace X by 1, 2 or 3)
- Every single js/media/skin base url is explicitely specified and common for all aliases (e.g. http://my.domain.local/js/)
- index.php is tweaked so it can handle "REDIRECT_" server vars :

  ```
  /* Store or website code */
  $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
  if ('' == $mageRunCode) {
      $mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : $mageRunCode;
  }

  /* Run store or run website */
  $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : 'store';
  if ('store' == $mageRunType) {
      $mageRunType = isset($_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_TYPE']) ? $_SERVER['REDIRECT_MAGE_RUN_TYPE'] : $mageRunType;
  }
  ```

## What I get

This config is not enough (or is wrong) to make it work :

- In `index.php`, when I dump `$mageRunCode` just before the `Mage::run()` line, I get the correct value
- All homepages work (http://my.domain.local/aliasX/)
- When I set RewriteBase to `/alias1/`, all `/alias1` based urls are working but not the others
- All other aliases' urls are redirected to alias1 homepage (and the dump shows the alias1 run code). This is normal, as I set RewriteBase to `/alias1/`

## What I already tried and isn't described above

- I tried tu use `<Location>` in my vhost config to set conditional RewriteBase. But with Locations set, my urls are not correctly redirected to `index.php` and I get the good ol' white apache 404 page (with apache error logs like this one : `File does not exist: /var/www/html/dev-site/code/catalog, referer: http://my.domain.local/alias1/`)

## What I dont want

vhost aliases pointing to subdirectories + duplicated `.htaccess` and `index.php` in these subdirectories

Any help, clue, link - you name it - will be **highly** appreciated (I'm not a sysadmin and currently wasting my client's money not being able to solve this issue)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/dev-site/code"
ServerName my.domain.local
RewriteEngine On
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias1.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=pf_view
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias1.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias2.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=es_view
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias2.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias3.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=ta_view
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/alias3.* MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
<Directory /var/www/html/dev-site/code>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AllowOverride All
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
</Directory>
```

Comment: Without RewriteBase i'm getting a Magento 404 error (skinned) for any page, home pages included. 

With a RewriteBase (say, `/alias1/`), I'm getting a brutal Internal Server Error With following apache error log :
`Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`